# In Elasticsearch, how do I combine a normalizer with a nested object?

Tags: elasticsearch

At a high level overview, my use case requires a nested object and I would also like to perform exact case-insensitive matches on my nested objects.

I've started with the example here:

https://www.codementor.io/mehuljain/case-insensitive-exact-matches-in-elasticsearch-nny7ii7fw

which does almost exactly what I want, except it doesn't use nested objects.

I've tried to modify the code on the above page by changing the type from `text` to `nested`:

```
PUT titles
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "default": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "nested",
          "fields": {
            "normalize": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
            },
            "keyword" : {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This, however, doesn't work and I get an error message.

How do I perform a case insensitive exact matching search on a nested object in Elastic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with nested object you need to define its `properties` and not `fields`.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "default": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {                       <----------- should be properties and not fields
            "normalize": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
            },
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Based on above change `title` will be and object which two properties namely `normalize` and `keyword`.